# http file validation for html5

Tags: http, caching, browser

What methods are used by the browser to ensure that all parts on a web page have been downloaded to the client successfully. This includes all html, css and javascript.

I have seen the etag in the http headers.

Does the browser have the ability to re-download content if a connection fails?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the length of the content is given in the HTTP response, so that the browser can verify that it got all data. If a connection fails or if it breaks in the middle of the data the browser will not automatically retry the download. Depending on the content type the browser might display the part it received before the connection broke. A re-download need to be triggered by the user (e.g. Refresh page).

Etag is not for verifying the download, but setting a "tag" for the response and reloading it only if the tag changed (e.g. for caching). While Etag is often a checksum over the content it does not need to be done this way.

There is a Content-MD5 header for giving a checksum of the content, but it is not widely used and I'm not sure if current browser even check this tag.